# How to splice into existing buttons?

Tags: voltage-level, relay, remote-control, wires

I want to control a kettle. It has 4 buttons and a digital disply of the temp. I would like the buttons and disply to remain functional. I just want to make the buttons remoteky pressabke. The buttons are at 5v. There is an almost bread‐board like set of little sockets where they connect to the higher voltage part of the kettle. (Where I see the kettle's built in relay, that powers the buttons and displsy.)k

If I have a 2nd set of wires to my arduino feed into these sockets would there be an issue with the signal from arduino going *to* the buttons?

Also, I think I might need a relay if I later adapt this for spark/particle core because it is 3.3v is there such a relay?

Comment: It might be useful to post a photo of the circuit board/connections.

Comment: From safe to less safe, use an opto-isolator; transitor; resistor; direct connection.